# EXISTS clause and JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Query 1

```
select ename,deptno 
from emp1 
where exists 
(select deptno from dpt where dpt.deptno=emp1.deptno AND deptno>20);
```

returns ename corresponding to the conditions imposed on the deptno field in the subquery

Query 2

```
select ename,deptno 
from emp1 
where exists 
(select deptno from dpt where deptno>20);
```

but in the query 2 the result contains all the values of the fields ename and deptno

**What changes the result set in both the queries?** Is it because of the join? How actually does the join work to bring a different result set in query 1? Why is the where condition is being considered in the query 1 and not in query 2 ?

```
 legends:
 empname is employee name in the table emp,
 deptno is department no. which is the common field in emp and dept tables.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First query is **correlated subquery**:

> Correlated Subquery is a sub-query that uses values from the outer
>   query. **In this case the inner query has to be executed for every row
>   of outer query.**

```
select ename,deptno 
from emp1 
where exists 
(select deptno from dpt where dpt.deptno=emp1.deptno AND deptno>20);
```

You can rewrite it to:

```
select e.ename, e.deptno 
from emp1 e
join dpt d
  on d.deptno = e.deptno
where d.deptno > 20;
```

Second query (noncorrelated/simple subquery):

> A noncorrelated subquery is subquery that **is independent of the outer
>   query** and it can executed on its own without relying on main outer
>   query.

```
select ename,deptno 
from emp1 
where exists 
  (select deptno from dpt where deptno>20);
```

Is equivalent to (if there exists something is subquery):

```
select ename,deptno 
from emp1 
where 1 = 1
```

Or (if subquery returns nothing):

```
select ename,deptno 
from emp1 
where 1 = 0
```

Comment: I really appreciate you method of explaining things. So basically a correlated subquery is when there is a relation (join) between the tables in outer query and tables in subquery ? thank you so much for responding.

Comment: @ManushreeMishra A correlated subquery is when you refer from subquery to outer query. In your example `where dpt.deptno=emp1.deptno`. Clue is that correlated subquery is executed for each row from outerquery and noncorrelated is executed once

Comment: So referring is basically done by inner join or can be done like this too : emp.deptno  inside  a subquery?

Comment: @ManushreeMishra Yes, it can be done by refering `emp.deptno`. Keep in mind that you refer to the same table twice you need aliases like:
`SELECT * FROM emp1 e1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM emp1 e2 WHERE e1.deptno = e2.deptno AND ...`

Comment: Thank you so much.I wish you could be my instructor :) SQL is really an intricate language.

Comment: I had a question that is there a rule regarding which tables alias should be written first when doing a join should it be first of the table which shares the query in which join condition is mentioned? like for above case should it be like this: emp.deptno=dpt.deptno or dpt.deptno=emp.deptno (I've not used alias here for the sake of clarity but i remember your point)

Comment: @ManushreeMishra When you use `ON` or `WHERE` there is no difference between `emp.deptno=dpt.deptno or dpt.deptno=emp.deptno`. Like in Math a = b is the same as b = a